# Android dotted underline is staying in middle of textview

Tags: android, xml

I want to show a dotted underline below the textview, following are my codes

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/contact_num"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingTop="4dp"
  android:text="1234567890"
  android:background="@drawable/dashed_line"
  android:layerType="software"
  android:textSize="20dp" />
```

dashed_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/oceanBlue"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

and the textview looks as above
    [image: textview looks like this]

can anyone help me to get the dotted line below to the textview?

tried with drawableBottom also but no use

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dashed_line"
```

Comment: Try this link https://mobikul.com/android-strike-textview/

Comment: @Srikanth look my code

Comment: Hi @ND1010_,  Vishva dave's code is worked, later will try your code also. Thanks man.

Comment: then you should up wot to me if you like my code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use this file for dotted line :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:left="-5dp"
        android:right="-5dp"
        android:top="-5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <stroke
              android:color="@color/oceanBlue"
              android:dashWidth="2dp"
              android:dashGap="3dp"
              android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

then add

> **android:background="@drawable/dashed_line"**

Comment: Doesn't this code work for you ? 

    android:background="@drawable/dashed_line"

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like this(Under Line)

```
    TextView contacttv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactTextView);

    contacttv.setPaintFlags(contacttv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView ..... 
    ..........
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted_line" />
```

**dotted_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        android:dashGap="15px"
        android:dashWidth="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to add dotted line below textview:
dash.xml(drawable xml)

```
<item
    android:left="-5dp"
    android:right="-5dp"
    android:top="-5dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:dashGap="5dp"
            android:dashWidth="5dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and in your textview xml :

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/segment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dash"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="First segment"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
tv.setText("This is strike-thru");
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: No @Abhishek Charismatic i want my dotted underline bottom of the textview